# what value to be assigned in searchContext for dlapp/search jsonws in Liferay

Tags: json, web-services, liferay-6

I want to call the json web service of liferay that is dlapp/search,
the problem I am facing is what value to passed to searchContext object in json web service.

Each time I call the service using correct repository-id and correct lucene query in the parameters.

But I am confused  which value should be provided to searchContext for correct service results.

Comment: can you initliaze ServiceContext using constructor and pass it?

Comment: its searchContext not ServiceContext

Comment: My mistake, can you initliaze SearchContext using constructor and pass it?

Comment: This is the problem i want to solve how to i initialize searchContext in json parameters